# Trigger Gitlab-CI Pipeline only when there is a new tag

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have following gitlab-ci conf. file:

```
before_script:
  - echo %CI_BUILD_REF%
  - echo %CI_PROJECT_DIR%

stages:
  - createPBLs
  - build
  - package


create PBLs:
  stage: createPBLs
  script: 
    - xcopy /y /s "%CI_PROJECT_DIR%" "C:\Bauen\"
    - cd "C:\Bauen\"
    - ./run_orcascript.cmd


build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd "C:\Bauen\"
  - ./run_pbc.cmd
  except:
  - master

build_master:
  stage: build
  script:
  - cd "C:\Bauen\"
  - ./run_pbcm.cmd
  only:
  - master

package:
  stage: package
  script:
  - cd "C:\Bauen\"
  - ./cpfiles.cmd
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    name: "%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%"
    paths:
      - GitLab-Build
```

How can I add the rule that the pipeline will ONLY trigger if a new tag has been added to a branch? The tag should start with "Ticket/ticket_"

Currently he is building for every push.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to use pattern in `varibles-expression` using commits

Example

```
build_api:
 stage: build
 script:
  - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
  - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
only:
  variables:
   - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /(\[pipeline\]|(merge))/
```

Here i am saying that `only` execute that job when have **[pipeline]** or **merge** inside the commit. More info, here in
[gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#variables-expressions)

Answer (score 25):

You need to use [only](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified) syntax:

```
only:
  - tags
```

This would trigger for any `Tag` being pushed. If you want to be a bit more specific you can do:

```
only:
  - /Ticket\/ticket\_.*/
```

which would build for any push with the `Ticket/ticket_` tag.

Comment: Oh, that simple! Need i add this after every stage/ Job?

Comment: @Hendouz Yes, otherwise the other stages would be run on every push.

Comment: The pipeline runs aswell if i name a Branch as "Ticket/Ticket_xxx" but i want the pipeline only run if it has a tag with it. @Rekovni

Comment: Hmm, you might need to add `except: - branches`

Comment: I think I was mistaken in my more specific way of doing things, as that is more for any `refs` with `Ticket/ticket_`. Perhaps just use `only: - tags` which would kick off your build with any tags.

Comment: Is there any solution @Rekovni ? i still need a special syntax for tags..for now he triggers the build if there is ANY tag.

Comment: ⚠️ `only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.` [Gitlab 14.9](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.9/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)

Comment: any sample for filtering semantic versioning tags, and only trigger when the tag is on `main` or `master` branch?

Answer (score 10):

below could be more readable, see [only:varibles@gitlab-ci docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariablesexceptvariables) with `refs:tags`

```
only:
  refs:
    - tags
  variables:
    - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^[Tt]icket-.*/
```