# Trigger Gitlab-CI Pipeline only when there is a new tag, with some rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

in the answer of this ([Trigger Gitlab-CI Pipeline only when there is a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514416/trigger-gitlab-ci-pipeline-only-when-there-is-a-new-tag) ), I understand to set `only` as filter

But How can I trigger the pipeline only:

1. there is a new tag created, these tags are semantic versioning tags, how can I filter them? something like

```
only:
  - /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/
```

but the tags are not always as 1.0.2, sometimes, they have beta or fc, such as `0.2.3-rc.1` or `2.3.5-beta`, will the filter to be `/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+.*/` is fine?

2. second rule is, the trigger is only on master or main branch

Regarding the `Semantic versioning regex`, I found this gist

https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/62eeea161a13b80e39f5249281e17c39

the sample is too complex

```
^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(?:-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+)?$
```

Comment: I use this regex `^v(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)$`. This will match v1.1.1 but not v01.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Using `only` is deprecated in favor of `rules`.

> rules replaces only/except and they can’t be used together in the same job.
> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

Create a `rule` and check the [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_COMMIT_TAG` for your pattern.

```
job:
  script: echo "Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*/
```

You can list multiple of these rules. So if you want to execute the job also on every push to the `master` branch, you'd add another rule:

```
rules:
  - if: ...
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"
```

The extended pattern with `.*` at the end would be fine, but you could also be a bit more specific like this `(-[0-9a-zA-Z.]+)?` if you want to enforce a specific syntax.